# VC6 on Win7, SourceSafe diff viewer doesn't draw text on the left pane (when maximized)

Tags: windows-7, visual-sourcesafe, visual-c++-6

I recently upgraded my computer, and moved from XP to Win7. We have old VC6 projects which we continue to develop. But on Win7 SourceSafe's diff viewer behaves oddly, if it is maximized. On the right pane all the text is drawn, but on the left pane most of the text is missing - there is just gray background where there should be text.

When I move the cursor to those white lines, the text on them appears, but only on the line where the cursor is. One way to show all the text is to select everything in the left pane (like Ctrl+A). Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Have you tried running VSS in compatibility mode? Right-click on the icon, go to the Compatibility tab, and choose "Windows XP". You'll have to run it as an Administrator for this to work, but I suspect you have to do that for it to run at all.

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't help. However now I noticed that this problem only happens when the diff viewer is maximized. If it is in normal mode, even if the window is nearly as big as a maximized window, it won't happen. This is a good enough workaround for me.

Comment: You might also have to disable themes/composition. You're running an application that was *old* when Windows XP was released. Running it under Windows 7 just seems like an exercise in masochism. And let's be honest, VSS was never that great to begin with. My suggestion is that you migrate to an alternative as quickly as possible, either living with the incompatibilities or running it in a Virtual Machine as long as you have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Disable visual themes' on the application shortcut's 'Compatibility' dialog tab did the trick for me, even when maximized, as suggested by Cody Gray.  That is the only compatibility option I changed.  I had the problem, changed the checkbox to checked to select the setting, the problem went away.

Environment: Windows Server 2008 R2 with the Windows 7 Desktop Experience feature, Visual SourceSafe 2005.